# Effecting a Vertical Stretch on Some of the Words in a Title

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize

I would like to know if given a particular font size, if it is possible to vertically stretch the letters while maintaining the width size?

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth 5.25in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE{THIS \, PART \, IS \, OK}}
\vskip 18pt
{\large{\scshape{but this part}}}
\vskip 27pt
{\LARGE{\bf IS TO BE VERTICALLY STRETCHED}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces the output:

[image]

If possible, I would like to increase the vertical length of the letters in the words: ``IS TO BE VERTICALLY STRETCHED''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option it is use `scalerel` package. I have improved your old command: you can see `\textsc` and `\textbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\textwidth 5.25in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE{THIS \, PART \, IS \, OK}}
\vskip 18pt
{\large{\textsc{but this part}}}
\vskip 27pt
\vstretch{3}{\textnormal{\textbf \LARGE{IS TO BE VERTICALLY STRETCHED}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

With the option `\vstretch{<number>}{...}` you can increase vertically the text. Here there is the documentation of [scalerel](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf) package that it contains many options.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides `\scalebox{<hfactor>}[<vfactor>]{<stuff>}` to scale content either `h`orizontally or `v`ertically. A `?factor` of `1` leaves `<stuff>` unscaled within that direction; less than `1` reduces it in that direction; greater than 1 enlarges it in that direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \makebox[.4\linewidth][s]{\LARGE THIS PART IS OK}
  
  \vspace{18pt}
  
  {\large\scshape but this part}
  
  \vspace{27pt}
  
  \scalebox{1}[4]{\LARGE\bfseries IS TO BE VERTICALLY STRETCHED}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you want a width-specific stretching, you can use `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}`.